# How to control UIView in code

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

As you can see in the screenshot, I added a UIView(named SearchView) in IB to control in my code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIs3e.png

How can I load the UIView in my code programatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**FlipView Approach to load UIView Programmatically**

In .h file use this code

```
  @interface MainViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIView *secondaryView;
}
- (IBAction)toggleView:(id)sender; //Action for toggle view
- (IBAction)returnView:(id)sender;


@end
```

In .m

```
- (IBAction)toggleView:(id)sender {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                               forView:[self view]
                                 cache:YES];
        [[self view] addSubview:secondaryView];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    //Flips to front when "Done" is pressed
    - (IBAction)returnView:(id)sender {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                               forView:[self view]
                                 cache:YES];
        [secondaryView removeFromSuperview];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

You can check this tutorial http://www.vimeo.com/5653713 if any confusion.